# ubuntu 18.04 - 4.15 kernel didn't show up even after grub-update

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel, 18.04

My strange story of `grub-update`

I recently updated my ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 hoping that it would be stable. But after upgrade, my lost my kernel headers. When I check my current kernel version using `uname -r` it tells that I am on 4.13. So I tried installing kernel headers for that. But then that I shows that 4.13 kernel headers are not available. Strange!!!

So I installed 4.15 headers and updated grub. Even after upgrading grub (using `update-grub`), the grub shows as if 4.15 is not installed. So I deleted my 4.13 kernel and restarted. But now since 4.13 kernel is deleted, I am unable boot. It behaves as if no kernels were installed!!!

So I boot my system to Debian partition and upgraded my grub. This time after boot, It works fine and the grub shows 4.15.

What possibly could be the reason the 4.15 kernel didn’t show up in ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a` and `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' linux-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs apt-cache policy`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reboot after you have upgraded from 17.10? If you're using 17.10 sure you will get 4.13 kernel from `uname -r`

The update process looks like this:

1. You boot with 17.10 (kernel 4.13)
2. You upgrade your system to 18.04, got everything installed even the 4.15 kernel, you can check them with command `dpkg -l | grep '\-4.15.0\-'` (But you're still running 4.13 kernel now)
3. Since you have your system upgraded from Artful to Bionic, the package source list will change, this may explain why you can't get 4.13 header packages anymore.
4. Once you reboot your system, you should be boot with Bionic and 4.15 kernel.

---

Last but not least, try not to pull off the rock that you're standing right on it. i.e. remove the kernel that you're running.

If you want to remove a certain kernel, it's better boot to another kernel  first (either doing this on boot or use a tool like grub_selector, grub customizer) to avoid unexpected hassles.

Comment: unfortunately, even after reboot, 4.15 didn't show. I must have rebooted some 10 times. It showed up only after booting through Debian and then update-grub.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep '\-4.15.0\-' did show  results that 4.15 is installed. But still it didn't show up in grub